# How do I increment the index for display purposes only?

Tags: loops, go

This code starts printing the data from the `0` index but I want it to seem as if the index starts at `1`.

**Given Result**

```
0 Foo
1 Bar
```

**Required Result**

```
1 Foo
2 Bar
```

**Code**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []string{"Foo", "Bar"}
    for i, s := range a {
        fmt.Println(i, s)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add 1 to `i`

Comment: You can just use `fmt.Println(i + 1, s)`. or you have another question that I didn't understand?

Comment: *I want it to start the indexing from 1.* -> Are you saying you want to entirely skip the first item in the list? Or that you want it to print out the numbers as if the first index is 1?

Comment: Add an `if` statement `if i == 0: continue` to skip the first entry in the list.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve what you are looking for is by an increment as follows:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := []string{"Foo", "Bar"}
    for i, s := range a {
        fmt.Println(i+1, s)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 Foo
2 Bar
```